# Having issue with getting an .innerHTML to work properly while inside of an if statement

Tags: javascript, html

I have an .innerHTML statement that isn't working correctly, but only while within an if statement.

```
document.getElementById("music").innerHTML = "[MUSICPLAYERCODE]";
```

is the code that I'm using, and it's within this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var thedate - new Date();
var hourofday = thedate.getHours();

    if(hourofday == 0) {
 document.getElementById("music").innerHTML = "[MUSICPLAYERCODE]";
    }
 </script>
```

While outside of the if statement, the code works completely fine, however, inside the if statement it refuses to work. Even if I change the condition to just a plain true, the code still will not execute. I'm new to javascript, and I can't seem to find any error after looking for a couple hours. If it helps at all, the music player I'm using is at [Billy Tumblr Audio Player](http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/).

Comment: any error in your browser console

Answer (score 2):

I think you have added not just the `if` condition but also the code related to date calculation.

There you have a syntax error, used `-` instead of `=`. In your browser console you should see an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`

```
var thedate = new Date();
//          ^ = not -
var hourofday = thedate.getHours();

if (hourofday == 0) {
    document.getElementById("music").innerHTML = "[MUSICPLAYERCODE]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var thedate - new Date();` ?

Change it to:

```
var thedate =  new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
window.onload=function(){
    var thedate = new Date();
    var hourofday = thedate.getHours();
    if(hourofday == 0) {
     document.getElementById("music").innerHTML = "<H1>[MUSICPLAYERCODE]</H1>";
    }
 };
```